# difference between emberjs model's _data and _attribute?

Tags: ember.js, save, ember-data

I am using a model `App.License` which has a property called `expires_at`.

While editing a license, in `edit` method of `LicenseController`, I am setting it's expiry as :

```
this.get('model').set('expires_at', '2014-12-31');
```

Then I am doing `this.get('model').save();` to make a PUT request to server.
But in that request, expires_at parameter is send as the old value of model.

When I printed my model in console, it showed me `expires_at` in both `_attributes` and `_data`. Strange thing was the expires_at in _attributes was updated one, and the one in _data was old one (which was sent to PUT request). Other properties of license are getting set properly and are sent as PUT parameters except `expires_at`. Am I missing out on something very small but important thing? Any help on this is much appreciated.

Comment: `_attributes` are dirty properties, and `_data` is persisted properties, will you show your model definition?  Are you using Ember Model or Ember Data?

Comment: Hello. Thanks for clarification. The issue has been resolved. There was a mistake at back-end apparently.
:-)
Thanks a lot for your help. I got what you wanted to convey.